# Passing parameters to msbuild from within Visual Studio

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017

As the title says: How can I pass parameters to the msbuild process(es) initiated by Visual Studio?

I need to modify the `MSBUILDDEBUGPATH` parameter as our solution has many post-build events making use of xcopy (which I don't like, but thats the way it is).

This results in the creation of many batch files in the folder `C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp[guid].exec.cmd` which execution gets prevented by our greate HIPS software resulting in killing all `msbuild.exe` processes.

Comment: Hi friend, how many post-build events in your solution? Since I can't find the tmp[guid].exec.cmd files from the folder you mentioned. Maybe because I only use a simple project with several xcopy to test?

Comment: Hi Matze, I'm afraid we can't change the temp folder under AppData, I can't find the "MSBuildDebugPath"), which means this path is defined by default. Maybe you can try to add the folder in a white list of HIPS if possible.